# Unable to use Vuex Store in Nuxt layouts

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I am trying to use Vuex Store in my `layout` but can't figure out how to make it work.
Here is what I am doing:

**store/sources.ts**

```js
import { VuexModule, Module, Mutation, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import { store } from '@/store'
import axios from 'axios'

const { sourcesEndpoint } = process.env

interface Source {
  id: String
}

@Module({
  name: 'sources',
  namespaced: true,
  stateFactory: true,
  dynamic: true,
  store,
})
export default class Sources extends VuexModule {
  private _sources: Source[] = []

  get sources(): Source[] {
    return this._sources
  }

  @Mutation
  updateSources(sources: Source[]) {
    this._sources = sources
  }

  @Action({ commit: 'updateSources' })
  async fetchSources() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(`!!! ${sourcesEndpoint} !!!`)
    return sourcesEndpoint ? await axios.get(sourcesEndpoint) : []
  }
}
```

**store/index.ts**

```js
import { Store } from 'vuex'

export const store = new Store({})
```

**layouts/default.vue**

```js
<script>
import { getModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators'
import Sources from '@/store/sources'

export default {
  fetch() {
    const sourcesModule = getModule(Sources, this.$store)
    sourcesModule.fetchSources()
  },

  fetchOnServer: false,
}
</script>
```

And the error I get:

```
[vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Vue.use(Vuex), also, you are not including your module in the main store

```
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { Sources } from './sources'

Vue.use(Vuex)
export const store = new Store({
modules: {
    Sources 
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I am using `'vuex-module-decorators` for `Nuxt` where the `root` store is injected into the `sources` module. Injecting the sources module again in the root store would cause circular dependency.